# Why I can't cancel `StreamGroup` subscription immediately

Tags: dart

I want to listen to events from multiple `Stream` sources until I get a stop event. After that, I would like to unsubscribe. I expect that `takeWhile` cancels the subscription, but it doesn't seem to work until it's finished awaiting `Future`.

Here is my code below:

```dart
    void main() async {
      await StreamGroup.merge([_test2(), _test1()])
          .takeWhile((element) => element != -1)
          .forEach((element) {
        print('Element=$element');
      });
      print('Finished!');
    }
    
    Stream<int> _test1() async* {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield i;
      }
      yield -1;
    }
    
    Stream<int> _test2() async* {
      await longUserAction();
    
      for (var i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        yield i;
      }
    
      yield -1;
    }
    
    Future<void> longUserAction() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20));
```

What I except:

```
Element=0
Element=1
Element=2
Element=3
Element=4
Finished!
```

What I got:

```
Element=0
Element=1
Element=2
Element=3
Element=4
*long pause*
Finished!
```

Comment: Probably because you have that `Future` that waits 20 seconds.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, but I don't want to wait 20 seconds. I want to cancel as soon as `takeWhile` predicate satisfies

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my case:

```dart
class _SubscriptionData<T> {
  final Stream<T> source;
  final StreamSubscription<T> subscription;
  bool isClosed = false;

  _SubscriptionData(this.source, this.subscription);

  void cancelSubscription() {
    if (!isClosed) {
      isClosed = true;
      subscription.cancel();
    }
  }
}

class _MergeStreamController<T> {
  final StreamController<T> _controller = StreamController<T>();
  int workingStreamsCount = 0;

  _MergeStreamController(List<Stream<T>> sources, bool Function(T) predicate) {
    workingStreamsCount = sources.length;

    final List<_SubscriptionData<T>> subscriptions = sources
        .map((source) => _SubscriptionData(source, source.listen(null)))
        .toList(growable: false);

    void cancelAll() {
      subscriptions.forEach((sub) {
        sub.cancelSubscription();
      });
    }

    subscriptions.forEach((subsData) {
      subsData.subscription.onData((data) {
        if (!predicate(data)) {
          workingStreamsCount = 0;
          _controller.close();
          cancelAll();
        } else if (!_controller.isClosed) _controller.add(data);
      });

      subsData.subscription.onDone(() {
        if (--workingStreamsCount <= 0) _controller.close();
        subsData.cancelSubscription();
      });
    });
  }
}

/// Merges [sources] streams into a single stream channel
/// Stream closes when the first [source] stream emits event which is not satisfying predicate
/// or all streams done its work.
Stream<T> mergeStreamsWhile<T>(
        List<Stream<T>> sources, bool Function(T) takeWhile) =>
    _MergeStreamController(sources, takeWhile)._controller.stream;
```

```dart
void main() async {
  await mergeStreamsWhile(
          [_test2(), _test1(), _test3()], (element) => element != -1)
      .forEach((element) {
    print('Element=$element');
  });
  print('Finished!');
}

Stream<int> _test1() async* {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
  yield -1;
}

Stream<int> _test2() async* {
  await longUserAction();

  for (var i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }

  yield -1;
}

Stream<int> _test3() async* {
  return; // Simulate an empty stream
}

Future<void> longUserAction() => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20));
```

Output:

```
Element=0
Element=1
Element=2
Element=3
Element=4
Finished!
```